# Cordova and AdMob with plugin admob-plus-cordova

Tags: android, cordova, admob

I am brand-new to Cordova and mobile app development. I am following the instructions for the plugin admob-plus-cordova, to show a BANNER AD, here:

- https://admob-plus.github.io/docs
- https://admob-plus.github.io/docs/cordova/ads/banner

**The deviceready async event listener is firing, and all code before `await admob.start()` runs successfully, but not the `console.log('AdMob started.')`. I have done all I could see in the documentation, but admon-start() does not complete in order to do show the ad.**

#### Additional information

- The plugin is added successfully.
- No errors in my console when emulating Android. Build is successful.
- My Ad Unit is set up correctly, however, I am testing first, thus using the Google Test ad ca-pub-xxx/yyy.
- My Application ID is correctly configured in AndroidManifest (the plugin does this for me).
- My app build.gradle file implements the play-services-ads:20.3.0 (the plugin also does this for me).
- `mavenCentral()` and `google()` are loaded in my repositories.gradle file (the plugin also does this).
- Upon @Eric's comment below, I added a catch to the `await.admob.start()` promise. It does not execute the catch either - no output in the console when doing conbsole.log(e).

#### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:noHistory="true" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="ca-app-pub-mypublisher~informationhere" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.DELAY_APP_MEASUREMENT_INIT" android:value="true" />
```

#### index.js

```
let banner

document.addEventListener('deviceready', async () => {
    console.log('Running cordova-' + cordova.platformId + '@' + cordova.version + '. Starting AdMob');
    document.getElementById('deviceready').classList.add('ready');
    await admob.start().then(() => {
        console.log('AdMob started.');
    }).catch(e => console.log(e));
    banner = new admob.BannerAd({
        adUnitId: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111', // THIS IS A GOOGLE TEST AD
        position: 'top'
    })
    banner.config({
        marginTop: 10,
        marginBottom: 5,
        backgroundColor: 'black'
    })
    banner.on('impression', async (evt) => {
        await banner.hide()
    })
    await banner.show()
    console.log('Showing ad.')
}, false)
```

I can't help but think that I need to create a container for my app within my HTML file, but I am not finding anything indicating this while doing a Google search. As it stands, I am expecting to see "AdMob started." after the call the `admob.start()`.

Any ideas?

Comment: add a .catch to your admob.start() promise to see the error

Comment: Hi @Eric, thank you. I have done this, but I am not getting any output whatsoever in the console. I updated the question to indicate as such.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A friend offline of Stack Overflow showed me about chrome://inspect (apparently, it is not the same as the normal inspector when working with Cordova - I do not know why). It showed me an error which is not present in the normal code inspector. After resolving that error, the issue was resolved.

Comment: please share the working code & solution for others thanks

Comment: Sorry, that project has been cancelled by the client, and all source copies sent to client. I do not have the code anymore.

Comment: ok no issue my issue was also resolved using official documents